# trying to find associativity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups, associativity

Is the binary operation define by:
 **$x*Y = x+y-1$**

what my tutor has done:
$x*(y*z) = x *(y+z -1) = x+(y+z-1) = x+y+z-2$

My question:
how did he get $x+y+z$**-2**

Where did the '-2' come from?

I am simply trying to learn how he did this, thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a little mistake

$x*(y*z) = x *(y+z -1) = x+((y+z-1)\color{red}{-1}) = x+y+z-2$

Comment: Ah i see!
So he simply substituted the equation for 'y'?

Comment: @Ihatemath Indeed. Ley $Y=y+z-1$, then $x*Y=x+Y-1=x+(y+z-1)-1$

Comment: @Ihatemath If the question is answered, you can click the 'accept' button :)